# How to style elements in an EJS file with a style.css file

Tags: javascript, ejs

I was just experimenting here and there with [EJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScriptMVC#View), because I am new to it.

Then I thought, why not style elements with a conditional flow? Basically a particular element will look purple when the condition is true and it will look red when it is not. When I style the elements in the tag itself, it works, but it doesn't work when I link a *style.css* file with it.

```html
<body>
    <%if(4>3){%>
    <h1 style="color: blue;">4 is more than 3</h1>
    <% }else{%>
    <h1 style="color: red;">Something is very wrong</h1>
    <% }%>
</body>
```

This worked properly.

But when I tried to style it in *style.css*, it didn't work. What is the reason?

EJS file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%if(4>3){%>
        <h1 id="one">4 is more than 3</h1>
    <% }else{%>
        <h1 id="two">Something is very wrong</h1>
    <% }%>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```css
#one{
    color: purple;
}
#two{
    color: red;
}
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have exposed the files properly? Such as in Express.js you need to serve the static folder where your file is kept on root domain for this to work.

To check this, try going to your website and opening /style.css and see if it opens.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). Questions belong in comments to the question. Rhetorical questions should be transformed to statements, optionally with conditions/presumptions.

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.